# How to pass macro variable into macro variable name in SAS ?

Tags: macros, sas

```
%let val = '    run'; 

%macro rrun;
    %put successfully run;
%mend;

%macro x;
    %r%cmpres(&val.);
/*  %rrun;*/
%mend;%x
```

I"m trying to pass macro variable into macro variable name in SAS. to run %rrun using %cmpres(&val.) passing value to macro name "rrun" I don't understand why this doesn't work. when compress &val is "run"

How can I solve this and still passing &val ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have quotes in your macro variable?

```
166   %let val = '    run';
167   %put |%cmpres(&val)|;
|' run'|
```

If you want to dynamically generate the name of macro to call it works much easier if you first generate the name into a macro variable and then reference that macro variable. Otherwise you risk confusing the tokenizer.

```
%macro x;
  %local mname;
  %let mname=r%cmpres(&val);
  %&mname;
%mend;
%x
```

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for answer . I put '    run' for this example because the actual program was pulling array of variable from list of string from database.

Comment: Macro variable values do not need quotes, if they are there then they are part of the value. Unlike in SAS code where you need quotes so the compiler can tell a string literal from a variable name or a keyword. Use `CALL SYMPUTX()` in a data step or use the `TRIMMED` or `SEPARATED BY` keyword in SQL code to generate macro variables without leading/trailing blanks.